# How to draw tables with correct column widths and correct centering of multicolumn items?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

[image]

I would like to put the `$\omega_1$` and `$\omega_2$` terms right in the middle of two columns.

If I make the columns equally wide -- 2em in the code below -- the result is very poor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}%
                             {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{c | *{2}{>{$}w{c}{2em}<{$} |}}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{$m$}     & \mcc{$\hat{m}$}     \\
\cline{2-3}
$m$       & x+2\alpha-1   & 1-\alpha-x   \\
\cline{2-3}
$\hat{m}$       & 1-\alpha-x   & x   \\
\cline{2-3}
\mcc{}  & \mcc[2]{$\omega_1$}
\end{tabular}
\hskip 21mm
\begin{tabular}{c | *{2}{>{$}w{c}{2em}<{$} |}}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{$m$}     & \mcc{$\hat{m}$}     \\
\cline{2-3}
$m$       & y   & 1-\alpha-y   \\
\cline{2-3}
$\hat{m}$       & 1-\alpha-y   & y+2\alpha-1   \\
\cline{2-3}
\mcc{}  & \mcc[2]{$\omega_2$}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to change the "3pt", but it controls the height rather than width.

Comment: You could use a third row, with `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\omega_i}`.

Comment: Please tell us how you generate the off-center `\omega_1` and `\omega_2` terms.

Comment: This has been asked again as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648669 which is phrased nearly the same, and has a much clearer title.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with both `tabular` environments is that you've set the column widths to `2em`, which is simply much too narrow.

In the following, I've switched your sample code from using `tabular` to `array` environments to declutter the code, by getting rid of lots of `$` inline math mode initiators and terminators. To get compact-looking tables, I suggest you measure the widths of the widest columns (called `\lenA` and `\lenB` below) and use these lengths instead of `2em`. The result is shown in the middle row of tables in the following screenshot.

There's still a nagging typographical problem, though: the `\omega_1` and `\omega_2` terms are mathematically, *but not optically*, centered. What's the (optical, or aesthetic) problem? The `\omega` glyphs, which visually dominate the `\omega_1` and `\omega_2` terms, are not placed right below the vertical rule; in consequence, the terms `\omega_1` and `\omega_2` do not "look" they're centered within the table. To achieve the desired optical centering, I suggest you place the `1` and `2` subscript terms in `\mathrlap` wrappers, so that the centering is performed on the `\omega` glyphs.

I've hightlighted the omega terms in the middle and bottom rows of the following screenshot to highlight the mathematical vs. optical centering issue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% pre-existing code
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}%
                             {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

% new code
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathrlap' macro 
% measure appropriate column widths:
\newlength\lenA
\settowidth\lenA{$x+2\alpha-1$} % for left-hand side array
\newlength\lenB
\settowidth\lenB{$y+2\alpha-1$} % for right-hand side array


\begin{document}

%% original version: incorrect column widths -- why 2em ?
\[
\begin{array}{c | *{2}{w{c}{2em} |}}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{m}     & \mcc{\hat{m}}\\
\cline{2-3}
m       & x+2\alpha-1 & 1-\alpha-x   \\
\cline{2-3}
\hat{m} & 1-\alpha-x  & x   \\
\cline{2-3}
\mcc{}  & \mcc[2]{\omega_1}
\end{array}
\hskip 21mm
\begin{array}{c | *{2}{w{c}{2em} |}}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{m}     & \mcc{\hat{m}} \\
\cline{2-3}
m       & y           & 1-\alpha-y   \\
\cline{2-3}
\hat{m} & 1-\alpha-y  & y+2\alpha-1   \\
\cline{2-3}
\mcc{}  & \mcc[2]{\omega_2}
\end{array}
\]

%% appropriate column widths, but naive centering of \omega_i terms
\[
\begin{array}{c | *{2}{w{c}{\lenA} |}}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{m}     & \mcc{\hat{m}}\\
\cline{2-3}
m       & x+2\alpha-1 & 1-\alpha-x   \\
\cline{2-3}
\hat{m} & 1-\alpha-x  & x   \\
\cline{2-3}
\mcc{}  & \mcc[2]{\omega_1}
\end{array}
\hskip 21mm
\begin{array}{c | *{2}{w{c}{\lenB} |}}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{m}     & \mcc{\hat{m}} \\
\cline{2-3}
m       & y           & 1-\alpha-y   \\
\cline{2-3}
\hat{m} & 1-\alpha-y  & y+2\alpha-1   \\
\cline{2-3}
\mcc{}  & \mcc[2]{\omega_2}
\end{array}
\]

%% appropriate column widths and *optical* centering of \omega_i terms
\[
\begin{array}{c | *{2}{w{c}{\lenA} |}}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{m}     & \mcc{\hat{m}}\\
\cline{2-3}
m       & x+2\alpha-1 & 1-\alpha-x   \\
\cline{2-3}
\hat{m} & 1-\alpha-x  & x   \\
\cline{2-3}
\mcc{}  & \mcc[2]{\omega\mathrlap{{}_1}}
\end{array}
\hskip 21mm
\begin{array}{c | *{2}{w{c}{\lenB} |}}
\mcc{}  & \mcc{m}     & \mcc{\hat{m}} \\
\cline{2-3}
m       & y           & 1-\alpha-y   \\
\cline{2-3}
\hat{m} & 1-\alpha-y  & y+2\alpha-1   \\
\cline{2-3}
\mcc{}  & \mcc[2]{\omega\mathrlap{{}_2}}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating things, and I'm not quite sure why.

You can center the ω's just by using a multicolumn spanning the 2nd and 3rd column.

Since this is all in math mode, using an array makes more sense than a tabular environment.

My suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}%
                             {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}% controls vertical spacing
%\setlength{\arraycolsep}{5pt} % if you want to control cell padding
\[
\begin{array}{r|c|c|}
\mcc[1]{} & \mcc[1]{m} & \mcc[1]{\hat{m}} \\
\cline{2-3}
m & x+2\alpha-1 & 1-\alpha-x \\
\cline{2-3}
\hat{m} & 1-\alpha-x  & x \\
\cline{2-3}
\mcc[1]{} & \mcc[2]{\omega_1}
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{r|c|c|}
\mcc[1]{} & \mcc[1]{m} & \mcc[1]{\hat{m}} \\
\cline{2-3}
m & y & 1-\alpha-y \\
\cline{2-3}
\hat{m} & 1-\alpha-y  & y+2\alpha-1 \\
\cline{2-3}
\mcc[1]{} & \mcc[2]{\omega_2}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: arrays]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`, which is similar to the classical `{array}` (of the package `array`).

In that environment, there is a key `hvlines` to draw all the rules, excepted if there is ``exterior'' rows and columns, which are specified by the keys `first-col`, `last-col`, `first-row` and `last-row`.

In order to have the same width for the columns of both environments, I have used the environment `{NiceMatrixBlock}` with its dedicated key `auto-columns-width` (by design, the width computed by this key does not apply to the exterior columns, which is what we want).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]%
\NiceMatrixOptions{first-row,first-col,last-row=3,hvlines,cell-space-limits=4pt}%
$\begin{NiceArray}{cc}
        & m           & \hat{m} \\
m       & x+2\alpha-1 & 1-\alpha-x \\
\hat{m} & 1-\alpha-x  & x \\
        & \Block{1-2}{\omega_1}
\end{NiceArray}
\hspace{21mm}
\begin{NiceArray}{cc}
        & m           & \hat{m} \\
m       & y           & 1-\alpha-y \\
\hat{m} & 1-\alpha-y  & y+2\alpha-1  \\
        & \Block{1-2}{\omega_2}
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}

\end{document}
```

**You need several compilations.**

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: +1 Out of curiosity, is there a way to know how many compilations are required depending on the contents without trial and error? (for those of us using `arara` and starting to use your package)

Comment: @JamesT: The number of compilations which is required when starting from scratch (i.e. without any `aux` file) is a deterministic function of the functionalities and options used, but it would be rather complicated to explicit that function. I don't know `arara` but I use `latexmk` and I know that `latexmk` does as may compilations as required by comparison of two consecutive versions of the `aux` file (in fact, usually, one compilation more than the number of compilations actually required because of the last comparison). I know that Overleaf uses also `latexmk`.